# Javascript set selectbox selected value by string value (not by selectedindex)

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of form elements (select,checkbox,textbox etc.) which are dynamically created by values coming from database.

There is a submit button at the bottom of form. I want to show same form value for next record. So I want to keep form elements values for after submit.

For example selectbox.

```html
<select name="parameter-1" id="parameter-1" class="form-control2">
                  <option value="Solid">Solid</option>
                    <option value="Liquid">Liquid</option>
                    <option value="Gas">Gas</option>
</select>
```

After submit I cant find selected index of parameter-1 so I cant use setselected index. Is there a way to set select by to having value "Liquid" option?

Comment: I can set it with php but there are a lot of form elements, so php code will make it hard to edit. But it is my last option.

Comment: share complete code, how you are creating `dynamically created` ?

Comment: complate code is too large to understand. It looks like a google form, or a jotform design. I save form element types and labels at design screen then run at this page.